# Objective C -Condition to check if folder is desktop or not

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to check if particular item selected is folder or file.I have set flags for that isDir and isFile.

Once an item selected is a folder , I set isDir=true but I need to set another flag if the particular folder selected is a Desktop.

What can be the condition for that in Objective C.

Comment: Isn't it just the matter of comparing a particular item path with that of the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the last part of the string and compare this to your desktop folder

```
    NSString *lastPart = [filePath.absoluteString lastPathComponent];
```

or, if your filePath is already an NSString and not an NSURL

```
    NSString *lastPart = [filePath lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: filePath is NsString type and when it try to do filePath.absoluteString it throws the error saying Property 'absoluteString' not found on object of type NSString